# How can I control the display order of child Forms in a MDI Form

Tags: c#, winforms, display, mdi

When I use an `MDI` Form I have a problem. My source code just like this:

```
private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form[] charr = this.MdiChildren;
        int i = 0;            
        foreach (Form chform in charr)
        {
            chform.Dock = DockStyle.Top;                
        }
        this.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.TileHorizontal);
    }
```

The numbers of child Forms is more then 3. In order to display them correctly after the `LayoutMdi()` method is called, I had to set the `Dock` property of all child Forms to `DockStyle.Top`.

After calling `LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal)`, clicking the Title Bar of the first child Form, this child Form is displayed at the bottom of the `MDI` parent automatically.

I want that the clicked child Form maintains it's original position.
Is there any idea for this question?

Comment: Calling just `this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal)` without docking then MDI Children?

Comment: @Jimi If calling just this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal), it doesn't work correctly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691902/mdilayout-tilevertical-doesnt-work-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the linked question - where it was suggested to set the `Dock` property to adjust the `MDIChild` Forms position - and the currently reported behavior, it is probably preferable to define the layout the `MDIChild` Forms without the help of automatic feature.

This allows to perform any layout logic that seems appropriate.

In the example, the `MDIChildren.Height` is calculated in relation to the `MDIParent.ClientSize.Height` and the number of opened `MDIChildren`, then multiplied by a values: in the sample code by 2, twice the base measure.

This Multiplier allows to define the `Horizontal Tile Height` of the `MDICHildren` quite precisely. Of course, you could implement some other logic that applies the multiplier only when there are at least 3 opened `MDIChildren`.

All the `MDIChildren` are re-sized to match the `MDIParent.Width` and the calculated `Height`, then ordered by Name and positioned from top to bottom.

Set different values of `HorizontalTileHeightMultiplier` to see how the `MDIChildren` are positioned in the `MDIParent.ClientArea` (`MdiClient`).
This multiplier could also be used as a custom Property in the Application, available to its Users allowing a custom tiling of the Forms.

The layout code is provided as a private method, so it can be easily used in different event handlers to perform/maintain the selected layout (the `MDIParent.Resize`, for example).
This method can also be easily adapted to replace the `MdiLayout.TileVertical` if required.

```
private float horizontalTileHeightMultiplier = 2;

private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TileHorizontal()
}

private void TileHorizontal()
{
    int openedForms = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1;
    if (openedForms < 2) return;

    int startLocation = 0;
    int childrenHeight = 
        (int)((ClientSize.Height / openedForms) * horizontalTileHeightMultiplier);

    List<Form> children = MdiChildren.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToList();
    foreach (Form child in children)
    {
        child.Size = new Size(ClientSize.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth - 4, childrenHeight);
        child.Location = new Point(0, startLocation);
        startLocation += childrenHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it.

Comment: I have tried it, it works! As what you had said, automatic feature is the reason that caused this problem(But how, I don't know yet). Thank you again.

Comment: @ballshark  Read the description I wrote [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471230/auto-resize-multiple-windows-forms-being-rendered-on-panel?answertab=active#tab-top) on the objects layout rules when docking/anchoring,especially in relation to the `BringToFront`/`SendToBack` behaviour.