# True size of my MDI Client area - height - 14?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

I am trying to center an MDI Child window in the center of my parent window's client area. By trial and error, I had found the following to work:

((parent.ClientSize.Width - 4)-centerchild.Width)/2, ((parent.ClientSize.Height - 14)-centerchild.Height)/2

I figured the 4 that I subtract from the width is the size of the border on either side, and I am able to get that number by either getting the MDIClient control within the parent (thanks to stack overflow for my finding that), or by subtracting SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width * 2. This makes sense to me.

I am having a much harder time figuring out why I need to subtract 14 from the height. Assuming the bottom border is 2, that still leaves a number of 12 which I cannot reconcile with anything. (If there's also a top border of 2, then t hat still leaves 10 unexplained.) I have looked into the following:

- Getting the MDIClient control within the parent does not get me that exact height as it does the width. Rather, it gets me parent.ClientSize.Height - **28**, which is double the difference I worked out by trial and error. 28 might represent a bottom border (2) + a top border (2) + the height of the menu strip (24), but that does not explain the 14 that I have found to be perfect.
- The Menu Strip height - as I said above, that's 24.
- Various other window-element measures in SystemInformation. Perhaps I overlooked one, but nothing seems to explain it to me.

I could certainly use the code with my trial and error numbers, but I hate to not understand. Does anyone have any ideas that would explain the (total) height difference of 14?

Comment: GetWindowRect on the MDI window? Windows version might matter, 10 has hidden stuff around the edges.

Comment: Do you have a ToolStrip / MenuStrip there? Do you merge ToolStrips of MDI Child Forms? Any scrollbars? Do you need to consider the size of these? This may help: [How can I control the display order of child Forms in a MDI Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53219672/7444103)

Comment: @Anders I don't see GetWindowRect as a method of my form or mdi client control in C#. ClientRect and DisplayRect give the the exact same measurements that I have been asking for an explanation of

Comment: @Jimi There is a MenuStrip on the parent window. The child which I am centering in the MDI client area has no title bar, no menu, no borders, nothing. It's a splash screen with an OK button on it.

Comment: In Windows 10+ you need to consider the invisible borders of a Window. These borders are still there even when your Form has no borders or Caption. In a border-less Form, consider `7x2` as the invisible borders size. Otherwise, it's `(7+1)x2` (when the Form is not moved. While it moves, this size changes).

Comment: Anyway, if you set `centerchild.Location = new Point((centerchild.Parent.ClientSize.Width - centerchild.Width) / 2, (centerchild.Parent.ClientSize.Height - centerchild.Height) / 2);` (with `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual`, of course), it should be centered inside the MdiClient. If it's not, post the code that creates this MDI Child Form and any property set in the Designer.

Comment: @Jimi But I've done that and it's still not quite right. mdi_client.ClientRectangle is the right width, but the height is 14 less than I know it to be based on trial-and-error calculation. To be clear:

ClientRectangle of MdiParent window = 1280 x 657
ClientRectangle of MdiContainer control = 1276 x 629
size of display area within client window, determined by Trial & Error = 1276 x 643.

I'm trying to figure out what that 643, which calculations give me perfect centering within the client area (the space between the bottom of the menu and the bottom border) represents internally.

Comment: The difference is the Height of the MenuStrip. Why do you care about it? Where do you want to center this Mdi Child Form? Inside its *natural* container (the MdiClient) or something else? The snippet I posted centers it in the MdiClient, hence excluding the MenuStrip. -- If you don't see it centered, then you have a scaled Screen and your app is not DpiAware. Or are you calculating the child Form's Location before you set the MenuStrip (`this.MainMenuStrip = [The MenuStrip Instance]`)?

Comment: @jimi wrote my previous message before seeing what you said about invisible borders. that sounds exactly like what I must be dealing with, since 14 is the number that my calculations are off by. Do you know if that's some sort of environment setting? Or would I account for it simply by using the constant? I would now hazard a guess that it's not the size of the container that's off, but my perception of the size/placement of the Mdi child.

Comment: Using that code, it doesn't matter what the size of invisible borders is, since it's part of the calculation. The borders are present in all 4 sides. When setting the Location, they're also there, so nothing changes. -- Make the MdiParent very small, just a little larger than the Mdi Child (so it's easier to evaluate the child Form position, just eyeballing it). Set the MenuStrip beforehand then set the Location of the Mdi Child Form. The MdiParent must be already created and ready to be shown, or already shown, to get correct measures.

Answer (score 1):

It seems none of the framework functions will give the correct dimensions for the MDIClient, nor will API functions like GetWindowRect or GetWindowInfo.  Derive from NativeWindow to subclass the MDIClient window and peek at WM_NCCALCSIZE when it comes across with wparam==true in which case lparam points to a NCCALCSIZE_PARAM struct that will have the right values.

```
     struct NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS
         {
            public RECT rcNewWindow;
            public RECT rcOldWindow;
            public RECT rcClient;
            IntPtr lppos;
         }
```